# react-native or iOS iphone App Webview Splash image

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen

My target is to show splash screen till my Webview url is fully loaded. It is react native app, but I guess any suggestions for iOS will work as well. Does that possible?

Answer (score -1):

To show a splash screen when the app is loadin you can check out this project on Github: [react-native-splashscreen](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-splashscreen).

This can be installed using npm:

```
npm install react-native-splashscreen --save
```

Usage:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    Text,
} = React;
var SplashScreen = require('@remobile/react-native-splashscreen');

var SplashViewApp = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    },
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                   Lorem Ipsum..
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SplashViewApp', () => SplashViewApp);
```

Otherwise use something like [react-native-loading-spinner-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay). Install it through:

```
npm install --save react-native-loading-spinner-overlay
```

Use as follows:

```
import React, { View } from 'react-native';

import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };
  }

  /* eslint react/no-did-mount-set-state: 0 */
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        visible: !this.state.visible
      });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Spinner visible={this.state.visible} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This project has no multi resolutions for splash screens